# VBA Collection add item to a specific place

Tags: vba, collections, addition

I would like to remove a specific item from a collection, then add a different value to its place.

For example:

```
Sub test()

Dim col As Collection
Set col = New Collection

col.Add (10)
col.Add (20)
col.Add (30)
col.Add (40)
col.Add (50)

col.Remove (3)
col.Add ("x", ,3) 'error here

End Sub
```

When I write the col.Add line it says *Compile error, expected: =* If I just write

```
col.Add ("x")
```

it works just fine, but it puts the value to the end not being the place defined.

It may be trivial, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply lose the parentheses;

```
col.Add "x", , 3
```

For

```
10
20 
"x"
```

`("x")` works as the parens are not part of the call to `add` rather they mean *evaluate `"x"`* so are valid (but unnecessary) for any single value which is then passed to `.add`.